# Would an HBase Scan perform better with multiple Column Families or single Column Family?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I would like to store an object (payload) along with some metadata in HBase.

Then I would like to run queries on the table and pull out the payload part based on metadata info.

For example, let's say I have the following column qualifiers

- P: Payload (larger than M1 + M2).
- M1: Meta-Data1
- M2: Meta-Data2

Then I would run a query such as:

- Fetch all Payload where M1='search-key1' && M2='search-key2'

Does it make sense to:

1. keep M1 and M2 in one column family and P in another column family?  Would the scan be quicker?
2. Keep all 3 columns in the same column family?

Normally, I would do a spike (I may still need to) - I thought I ask first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to follow the advice given in [HBase Reference](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#number.of.cfs) and go with option #2 (*Keep all 3 col in the same column family*):

> Try to make do with one column family if you can in your schemas. Only
> introduce a second and third column family in the case where data
> access is usually column scoped; i.e. you query one column family or
> the other but usually **not both at the one time**.